# Reasons Behind Finding an IP addresses of Miners

Tags: transaction-fees, miner-configuration

I am wondering if Finding IP addresses of each miner, can help the transactions to be processed by them without waiting time in mempool or not?
I do not understand clearly why people are looking for IP addresses of the miners?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary Bitcoin users would not care about the IP addresses of miners. Every Bitcoin node simply tells its peers (the "neighbors" of the node) about any new transactions they hear about. This way, the transactions get relayed across the network until everyone has heard about them, including the miners.

The waiting period is independent of how quickly the transaction gets to miners. Miners are constantly trying to find a block and succeed at random intervals. Whenever they find a block, they include whatever transactions they know about that pay the most fees, so beside a transaction just missing to get into a block, the wait is independent—it's simply until the next block is found that they fit into.

It's not clear to me in what scenario people might be trying to find the IP addresses of miners. Two that come to mind would be researchers that are trying to map Bitcoin mining activity, and attackers that want to hijack hash power.